# sparkR gapply SLOW compared with SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have a data set of ~8 GB with ~10 million rows (about 10 columns) and wanted to prove the point that SparkR could outperform SQL. To the contrary, I see extremely poor performance from SparkR compared with SQL.

My code simply loads the file from S3 the runs gapply, where my groupings will typically consist of 1-15 rows -- so 10 million rows divided by 15 gives a lot of groups. Am I forcing too much shuffling, serialization/deserialization? Is that why things run so slowly?

For purposes of illustrating that my build_transition function is not the performance bottleneck, I created a trivial version called build_transition2 as shown below, which returns dummy information with what should be constant execution time per group.

Anything fundamental or obvious with my solution formulation?

```
build_transition2 <- function(key, x) {

  patient_id <- integer()
  seq_val <- integer()

  patient_id <- append(patient_id, as.integer(1234))
  seq_val <- append(seq_val, as.integer(5678))

  y <- data.frame(patient_id, 
                  seq_val,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                  )
}


dat_spark <- read.df("s3n://my-awss3/data/myfile.csv", "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")


schema <- structType(structField("patient_ID","integer"),
                     structField("sequence","integer")
                     )


result <- gapply(dat_spark, "patient_encrypted_id", build_transition2, schema)
```

Comment: With 8GB R is almost sure to outperform Spark SQL (if computation is not very CPU intensive) if you just skip Spark completely. SparkR indirection won't give you any advantage here. Just saying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and wanted to prove the point that SparkR could outperform SQL.

That's just not the case. The overhead of indirection caused by the guest language:

- Internal Catalyst format
- External Java type
- Sending data to R
- ....
- Sending data back to JVM
- Converting to Catalyst format

is huge.

On to of that, `gapply` is basically an example of group-by-key - something that we [normally avoid](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) in Spark.

Overall `gapply` should be used if, and only if, business logic cannot be expressed using standard SQL functions. It is definitely not a way to optimize your code under normal circumstances (there might border cases where it might be faster, but in general any special logic, if required, will benefit more from native JVM execution with Scala UDF, UDAF, Aggregator, or `reduceGroups` / `mapGroups`).

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your clear explanation. Admittedly pushing the scope of OP but want to understand more here with a follow-up question. Is the nature of my problem (many small groups) itself a bad candidate for Spark/SparkR or would a different approach (eg use of reduceGroups) permit me to solve the problem with performance somewhat comparable to SQL?